# Smooth form resizing in Delphi Firemonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

If I create a Multi-Device application in Delphi 10 Seattle (no controls on the form), run the app., and resize the form to make it larger, I see a hint of a black background rectangle following my cursor and every so often the form jumps to the new position indicated by the black rectangle.

With a form loaded with many controls, the black background rectangle is much more pronounced (extending far outside the edges of the form especially if I drag the cursor fast) and there is a very noticeable delay before the form jumps to each new position. The enlargement of the form appears to take place in a series of big jumps. To my eyes, this is ugly. Is there any way to have the form enlarge smoothly rather than in this jerky fashion?

PS I just noticed this only occurs when compiled for Windows. Compiled for OS X, the form does enlarge smoothly.

Comment: I can reproduce this on a VirtualBox VM running Windows 10 but not on a "real" Windows 8.1. Does not matter whether compiled with XE7.1 or "10 Seattle".

Comment: I am indeed running on a virtual Windows - VMWare Fusion. Good to know it won't be an issue on a real Windows machine. Thanks for solving.

Comment: I experience the same on Parallels - Win 7. Haven't tried on real Win PC.